# Virtualbox Android: kernel panic not syncing tried to kill idle task

Tags: virtualbox, android

I can't run Android on Virtualbox, i followed this tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/ but i keep getting following error when installing (or running live) from iso:

```
kernel panic - not syncing: tried to kill idle task
```

the error is show cca 2 seconds right after the install/live option was selected

- Android version: x86 4.3 (from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/detail?name=android-x86-4.3-20130725.iso&can=2&q=))
- Virtual Machine settings: Linux 2.6 (not 64bit, but host pc is 64bit)
- Host Machine: Windows 8 64bit

I have tried Androind 4.2, Linux 2.6 64bit, Linux 2.4, nothings works.

Log: http://pastebin.com/ur9BYbHH

Answer (score 2):

I had the same or similar problem and found it was related to my virtualization options being disabled in my computer's BIOS.  After enabling them and re-enabling the virtualization options in VirtualBox, I was able to boot it up with no problems.

Comment: I have solved this months ago by downloading different ISO (and used whole different Android emulator in the end anyway) but thanks for answer.